# How I put a bytearray in python?

Tags: python

I tried to solve a `TypeError:bytearray out of range` in diferents forms but I fail fixing this. 
Someone knows **how I put a bytearray with 900000 bytes in python?**

Comment: This looks like an extension (or repeat) of your earlier question, http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15225/how-to-solve-a-indexerror-in-python of how to translate `new byte[900000]` from java into python, no?

Comment: I am using python in a raspberry pi. that is not count

Comment: It is more of an issue with Python, not an issue specific to the Raspberry Pi. If your issue was only occurring on the Raspberry Pi (you have tested it elsewhere and it works) or if it had to do with a Raspberry Pi specific topic, like the GPIO ports, then it would be on-topic here. Right now it would fit better on [so], as that is entirely programming oriented. Please don't feel that we don't want you here on Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange, this question is just better suited to [so].

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a python question, not a pi question, but anyway.  Check out the docs: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bytearray

> `bytearray([source[, encoding[, errors]]])`
>
> Return a new array of bytes. The bytearray type is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256. It has most of the usual methods of mutable sequences, described in Mutable Sequence Types, as well as most methods that the str type has, see String Methods.
>
> The optional *source* parameter can be used to initialize the array in a few different ways:
>
> **If it is an integer, the array will have that size** and will be initialized with null bytes.